# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 405 at WebserviceTest.vrn.App.main(App.java:38)

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am getting the above error while i am testing the the below given webservice using java.I am not getting the response.

Webservice is http://services.groupkt.com/state/get/IND/all

My code is

```
try {

        // create HTTP Client
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        // Create new getRequest with below mentioned URL
        HttpPost getRequest = new HttpPost("http://services.groupkt.com/state/get/IND/all");

        // Add additional header to getRequest which accepts application/xml data
        getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/xml");

        // Execute your request and catch response
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

        // Check for HTTP response code: 200 = success
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        // Get-Capture Complete application/xml body response
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));
        String output;
        System.out.println("============Output:============");

        // Simply iterate through XML response and show on console.
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Error is thrown here

```
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }
```

Comment: 405 is method not allowed.. Just check the method whether it's really GET or PUT or POST

Comment: service at `http://services.groupkt.com/state/get/IND/all` doesn't return in `application/xml` format, try changing to `application/json`

Comment: 405 usually means you either tried a GET on something that only allows POST method, or vice-versa, or you have tried http: on a method that requires https protocol

Comment: Just semantically, a POST without payload or at least some action-naming URL doesn't make sense, as a POST usually changes something on the server or sends some data. You most likely want to do an HttpGet.

Comment: thankyou Kulbhushan Singh